# Django FieldError when field is in model

Tags: python, django

Just recently merged some work in with a bunch of new fields. The offending field is in the model as written, double underscores and all, and it is in the database. It does not refer to `landslide.earthquake_related.risk_score`.

The error is when i try to annotate a query set in a django shell and get

```
qs = MyModel.objects.all()
qs.annotate(count=Count('my_field'))

Cannot resolve keyword 'landslide__earthquake_related__risk_score' 
into field. Choices are: ... landslide__earthquake_related__risk_score, 
landslides__precipitation_related__risk_score, ...
```

I'm using Django 1.4. Note 'my_field' is not the field in the error.

I'm guessing it may be something due to the double underscores, but I can't tell.

Comment: qs.annotate(count=Count('my_field'). Count is a keyword

Comment: It would be easier to help if you showed the actual code that is causing the problem.

Comment: The fields listed in the error are actual. The field listed in the annotate statement is fictional, because any field causes this error.  I can post some of the model if that helps, but it's only a DecimalField, so not really significant.

Comment: @Alasdair what code would help?

Comment: I bet you get the error even if you don't do the annotation. Right? But please, post how you construct `qs` because it would be very helpful to understand where the error is.

Comment: I don't get the error when I do `.values()` or index into the query set.

Comment: Except for the missing `)` in the snippet on SO there doesn't seem to be something obviously wrong. From the error code you have posted, is it correct that `MyModel` has a `landslide` as well as a `landslides` field? (the available choices suggest that). Does the lookup you are using in the `annotate` clause work when you are using it on a normal instance? (e.g. `foo = MyModel.objects.first(); print foo.landslide.earthquake_related`)

Comment: @sthzg I think you may have hit upon something. The field in the model is actually called `landslide__earthquake_related__risk_score` verbatim. I tried to make that clear, but it's actually as written a field in that model. Which makes me think that's what the problem is.

Comment: I see, makes sense then. Django's ORM will think the double underscores should follow a relation. I just setup a fresh 1.4 installation and reproduced the error. `syncdb` does create field names with `__` without an error (Django 1.8 e.g. throws an exception and doesn't let you migrate a model with a field name containing two underscores), but lookups throw the exception. I couldn't find a way to escape field names with  `__`, so if possible it might be best to rename these fields. (or give it another few hours and see if so. on SO has a solution)